# Should we have a "form-alter" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was pursuing questions today, and ran across [jQuery hotkeys plugin](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10093/jquery-hotkeys-plugin).

The accepted answer shows how to use `hook_form_alter()` to accomplish what the OP wanted to do.

Given that a lot of work with forms involves `hook_form_alter()`, should we have a "form-alter" tag?

I don't think that many people asking questions would know to use this tag, but others could add the tag as appropriate.

I am thinking that this may help people to find related questions/answers easier.

Comment: If this tag comes out, I'll be the first to add it as favourite

Answer (score 4):

I actually agree with having a form-alter tag. `hook_form_alter()` is surprisingly versatile, and is often the answer to many intermediate customizations. I think grouping them together would help clarify that specific function's flexibility and reuse.

Answer (score 2):

Tags are for questions, not for the answers; if an answer shows how to do a task using `hook_form_alter()`, that doesn't mean a question should be tagged [form-alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-alter).

[form-alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-alter) could be used for questions that are about `hook_form_alter()`, or how to alter a form. If there are enough questions that are specific for `hook_form_alter()`, the tag could be used.

Comment: Is there a discussion regarding tags on answers ? It could be useful in the scenario that Tim describes but on other hand becomes rapidly quite messy.

Comment: They are not planning to add tags to answers.